# Difficulty when filling rows and cells with a bidimensional array

Tags: java, excel, hashmap, apache-poi

There's a HashMap:

```
HashMap<String, Object> matrix = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

Considering that the Object is an ArrayList with data:

```
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.keySet().size() * 2; i += 2) {           
    keyRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(matrix.keySet().toArray()[i / 2].toString());
    for (int j = 5; j < (((ArrayList<String>) matrix.get(matrix.keySet().toArray()[i / 2].toString())).size() + 5); j++) {
        valueRow = worksheet.createRow((short) j);
        valueRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(((ArrayList<String>) matrix.get(matrix.keySet().toArray()[i / 2].toString())).toArray()[j - 5].toString());
    }  
}
```

As you can see, the outer loop fills the keyRow with the strings of the keySet() of the HashMap while lefting behind an empty cell in between (It gets incremented by 2).
The inner loop is supposed to fill cells under each key with each corresponding value (which is an ArrayList with more values, that's why is another loop). It works beautifully except for the fact that the APACHE POI worksheet.createRow() method OVERWRITES the previous results, giving the final result of just one key being properly filled.

Do you have any idea on how I can solve the problem? I thank you very much.

Comment: Do you implicitely think that `createRow()` returns an already existing row should it already have been created? You're wrong there. Check if `getRow()` returns `null` and only then call `createRow()`. I'm not totally sure, though. (The same goes for `createCell()`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is naive; learn to use the Collections API properly, full Generic typing,  Iterable for loops, and no pointless use of toArray(), map gets, or short.

I suggest you try:

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> matrix = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

int cell=0;
int row=0;
for (Map.Entry<String,Object> e : matrix.entrySet()) {           
    worksheet.createRow(row++).createCell(cell).setCellValue(e.getKey());
    Row valueRow = worksheet.createRow(row++);
    for (String v : e.getValue()) {
        valueRow.createCell(cell++).setCellValue(v);
    }
}
```

You may want to consider using a TreeMap or a LinkedHashMap if you want a sorted or source sequence list for the key value.

Comment: I'll give you the correct answer, because it was very useful to me and helped me to think through another angle, and because of the tips.